# How to validate an array of strings using express validator?

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

```
options = ['asdasda', 'asdasdas', 'asdasdasafsaafasfasfasfasfasfasasasasasdas', 'asd'];
req.check('options', 'Option must not exceed 30 characters').isLength({max: 30});
```

Am trying to validate each string in the array options. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to validate a variable you defined in your code, or is that just a sample of your request body?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you must use wildcards for that.

```
req.check('options.*').isLength({ max: 30 })
```

Comment: it does not throw an error if there is no key named `options`

Comment: @Cybersupernova yup because the above checks that every item in `options` matches the condition. It works the same as `Array.prototype.every`. You can enforce `options` to exist using other ways.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/api/validation-chain#isarray) you'd also need the following to ensure the array had elements. Notice it's without the asterisk meaning the field itself not the contents: `req.check('options').isArray({ min: 1 })`